# Sum of rows for a given column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add elements in rows from "list1" and "list2" using while loop. But getting `"KeyError: 'the label [7] is not in the [index]"`. I know the simple way to do this is:

```
df['sum'] = (df["list1"]+df["list2"])
```

But I want to try this with loop for learning purposes.

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({"list1":[2,5,4,8,4,7,8],"list2":[5,8,4,8,7,5,5],"list3": 
[50,65,4,82,89,90,76]})
d=[]
count=0
x=0
while count<len(df):
    df1=df.loc[x,"list1"]+df.loc[x,"list2"]
    d.append(df1)
    x=x+1
count=count+1
df["sum"]=d
```

Comment: how about adding python tag as well  ?

Comment: @W-B, I do not mean to be rude, but don't you have enough rep to do it yourself ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout I would like he do it by himself .PS : I do not want to be rude to him . :-)

Answer (score 0):

you are really close but just a few suggestions:

no need for both `count` and `x` values

you are getting the error because then len of df (7) falls outside the index which is what `loc` is looking for. That can be fixed by doing `len(df)-1`

you do not need to do `x = x+1` you can use `x+=1`

```
d=[]

x=0
while x <= len(df)-1:
    df1 = df.loc[x, "list1"] + df.loc[x,"list2"]
    d.append(df1)
    x += 1

df["sum"]=d
```